# Use classic C# Class Library to service as Data Access Layer for multiple platforms

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

**First of all**
I know the classic Class Library is not compatible with UWP projects, or Xamarin projects. This is not what this is about.

I'm very used to creating applications where a Web App and a Desktop Application (Win Forms) would shared the same database. I would simply create a Class Library (classic) and used as the `DbContext` for the whole solution. It was very simple. Back then, I was able to `Enable-Migrations` directly in the class library and it would work like a charm.

Nowadays, Windows Forms are deprecated, or rather, removed from Asp.NET Core and classic Class Libraries can't be referenced in UWP projects. I also can't enable migrations (`Add-Migration`, now the `enable-migrations` is obsolete) in UWP Class Libraries. It tells me to do it inside a UWP Application, not in a library.

Is there anyway to bypass this? I don't care if I have to create yet another layer to make some sort of "middle maning", as long as I don't have to create data access models in each application. This next project will have two UWP apps (one of them being design for IoT), an MVC Web App, and two Xamarin apps (Android and iOS).

I also accept structure related suggestions... Maybe I'm overthinking this. Thanks.

---

Edit:
I would like to add that I tried to use "Shared Project", and whilst it presents a nice tool, it doesn't do what I need.

Comment: Are you aware of the existence of [PCLs and shared projects](https://xamarinhelp.com/portable-class-library-pcl-vs-shared-projects/)?

Comment: @GertArnold PCL also doesn't allow migrations in the library, but I really didn't know about shared projects, and from a short reading, it seems like it'll work

Comment: Did you have any luck with the .NET Standard class library, sharing it between Windows Forms and UWP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you looked at [.NET Standard library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library)?

Maybe it will get you in the right direction with your project.

More info may be found in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38181004/can-i-build-uwp-with-net-core).

**EDIT:** [Here](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/guides/create-net-standard-packages) you can find an example on how to create a .NET standard library.

Comment: I'm guessing that's not a project type, because I didn't bump into it when trying to create different types of projects. I looked it up online, and I still couldn't figure out how to use that. Is it just a reference to add in?

Comment: After having sometime to experiment with the standard library, I can say that it's the best possible scenario for me, so I'm marking this down as the answer.

Comment: For sure at 2016 it wasn't, but for some time now it is a project type.